# After including 'espresso-contrib:3.1.0': Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestResources'

Tags: android, dependencies, build.gradle, android-espresso

After including the line (in order to use RecyclerViewActions for testing with Espresso):

> androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.0'

I get the error:

```
AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

More specifically

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.
```

And further into the logs:

```
error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found., sources=[/Users/****/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-1.0.0.aar/8cc334eb6bfbd0d390b8b779993d2020/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}
```

...

```
error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found., sources=[/Users/****/Documents/Code/AndroidStudioProjects/MyProject/app/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugAndroidTestResources/merged.dir/values-v28/values-v28.xml:11], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}
```

...

```
error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found., sources=[/Users/****/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-1.0.0.aar/8cc334eb6bfbd0d390b8b779993d2020/res/values/values.xml:1304:5-69], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}
```

...

```
error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
Message{kind=ERROR, text=error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found., sources=[/Users/****/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/appcompat-1.0.0.aar/8cc334eb6bfbd0d390b8b779993d2020/res/values/values.xml:1304:5-69], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}
```

...

```
error: failed linking references.
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    dataBinding.enabled = true
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.****.****"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/dbhelpers/java/'] } }
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            includeAndroidResources = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'


    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.0'

    androidTestImplementation "com.google.truth.extensions:truth-java8-extension:0.42"
    testImplementation "com.google.truth:truth:0.42"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade your compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 28. These resources are not present in SDK 26.

Comment: Do you still get the error about fontVariationSettings after upgrading to sdk 28?